# Why do I see more cell than numberOfRowInSection's rerun value when I scroll down?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Number of row is 3. But I see more cell in tableView when scroll. I see cells with height 94 with separator color. However, I want only 3 cells in table view. Why do I see more cells than 3? Can anybody explain it?

Thank you

```
    tableStyle.separatorColor = UIColor.red
    tableStyle.allowsSelection = false
    tableStyle.isScrollEnabled = true

    // register UINib for LogoStyle1, FieldStyle1, ButtonStyle1
    tableStyle.register(UINib(nibName: "LogoStyle1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LogoStyle1")
    tableStyle.register(UINib(nibName: "FieldStyle1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "FieldStyle1")
    tableStyle.register(UINib(nibName: "ButtonStyle1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ButtonStyle1")

    self.view .addSubview(tableStyle)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 120
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 272
    }else{
        return 94
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LogoStyle1", for: indexPath) as! LogoStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FieldStyle1", for: indexPath) as! FieldStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonStyle1", for: indexPath) as! ButtonStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    default:
        fatalError()

    }

    }
```

here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: show a screen shot of what you see.. you cannot see more than 3 cells here

Comment: I really see  I am gonna add it.

Comment: Answer updated. You see cells with separator color?

Comment: @John there are no cells there, just separators.. you can get rid of them by setting `tableFooterView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not cells, but the tableFooterView, which is filling the available space, get rid of it as such:

```
tableStyle.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you. It was filling the available space also It was repeating when scroll more and more.